# Creating transparent background in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have a button with a backgroun image of color white. My button is sitting on the toolbar which has a bacground color of Blue. When the button is sitting on the toolbar, the button looks white, however I want it to look like blue as the the background color of toolbar is Blue.

How should I achieve this in WPF.. Please let me know.

Comment: Initially you say you have a "backgroun image" then you ask how to set the "background color". Do you have an image or not?

Comment: I have background image. Also edited above post..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use an image? If the image is just a solid color, you're probably better off just setting the button's background to white and adjusting its opacity. Like:

```
<Button Background="White" Opacity="0.5" />
```

Where Opacity can be any value between 0 and 1.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure what you mean by "shades." Are you aware that you can set the background of a Button to a gradient? You'll want to change the colors I'm sure, but it will look something like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
         </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `System.Windows.Media.Color` `Transparent`, like this:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" />
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't help.. Is there any other mechanism?

Comment: It helped me with my issue, using Canvas to draw "over" image behind it - so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your image has transparency, WPF won't try to figure out what parts in your image should be see-through and what parts should be opaque. Check that your image editor can export images with transparency, most likely to PNG.

Comment: Do you know of any free tool that can do this? (for ex, Paint etc..)

Comment: @Vinjamuri - Paint.NET is free and can create png files. http://www.getpaint.net/